# JavaScript Random Message

Tags: javascript, php, message

I need to create a random message when there is a successful match in my PHP code, but I am unsure how to accomplish this with JavaScript. In my code, the PHP pulls the username and password from a file and then checks to see if that username and password entered by the user matches. If so they gain access and the form disappears to show a message (that I am trying to figure out how to do). If not, then access is denied and the form stays for them to try again.

I have tried changing the code to `onload`, `onclick`, and by `addEventListener`, but nothing will display. I have also tried changing the HTML tag to `element` and `p`. Is this not possible to do? I didn't think the `onclick` would be good since the submit button is clicked either way but I tried it to see if I could get it to work anyway.

**PHP**

```
    //NO ERRORS AVAILABLE AND THE BUTTON HAS BEEN PUSHED
    if (!$error && isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        echo '<div class = "output">
        <h1 class = "success">'.$msg.'</h1>
        <p id="welcomeDisplay" onload="newWelcome()"></p>
        <p id="welcomemsg"></p>
        </div>';
    }
```

**JavaScript**

```
var welcome = 
[
    "Success feels so good!",
    "You made it!",
    "You are worthy!",
    "Open Sesame",
    "Welcome to the dark side!",
    "Hola!",
    "So glad you are back!",
    "Hello, sunshine!",
    "Howdy, partner",
    "what's kickin', little chicken?",
    "Peek-a-boo!",
    "Ahoy, matey!",
    "Aloha!",
    "Bonjour!",
    "Hallo!",
    "Ciao!",
    "Konnichiwa!"
];

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------*/
function newWelcome()
{
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (welcome.length));    
    document.getElementById('welcomemsg').innerHTML = welcome[randomNumber];
}
```

Comment: `onload` can't be used on a `<p>` (only on document, window, img, frames, and scripts). You could just put `<script>newWelcome();</script>` at the end of your echo if your intention is to fire that function immediately after that HTML is inserted--that is, of course, assuming that your function is already defined (has already loaded). Binding it to `window.onload` is also a good option.

Comment: The only JavaScript I am allowed to have in my php file is `<script src="js\script.js" defer></script>`. Is there a way to accomplish this without adding more `<script>` tags?

Comment: @monkey84 Try using event handlers instead,
`$(document).on('click', '#welcomeDisplay', function(){  newWelcome();  });`

Comment: what is the name of the php script ?

Comment: The php file is `index.php`

Comment: and is that at root level of the site or within a sub-folder?

Comment: That's the root. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the php script is at root level you might try adding something like this to your `scripts.js` file but you might need to tweak it to account for no script name in the url or a path if it is in a sub-folder.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{
    let arr=location.href.split('/');
    let page=arr.pop();
    let path=arr.pop();
    /*
        You might need to use the path variable too!
    */
    if( page=='index.php' ){
    
        const welcome=[
            "Success feels so good!",
            "You made it!",
            "You are worthy!",
            "Open Sesame",
            "Welcome to the dark side!",
            "Hola!",
            "So glad you are back!",
            "Hello, sunshine!",
            "Howdy, partner",
            "what's kickin', little chicken?",
            "Peek-a-boo!",
            "Ahoy, matey!",
            "Aloha!",
            "Bonjour!",
            "Hallo!",
            "Ciao!",
            "Konnichiwa!"
        ];
        let msg=welcome[Math.floor(Math.random() * (welcome.length))];
        document.getElementById('welcomemsg').innerHTML=msg
    }
})
```